# Test - one-way ANOVA assumptions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I'm trying to solve some statistic problem, one of that requires to check if one way ANOVA assumption (normality) is satisfied.

The slide provided say to proceed as below:

hypothesis test

$\frac{e_{ij} - E(e_{ij})}{\sqrt{VAR_{between}/N}}$

check if 95% of residual are contained in interval.

---

This formula is not clear to me; I'd kindly like to ask if someone could provide me a link or book reference where I can find explanation about the formula and related meaning.

Comment: The same way the usual z-score is: observed minus expected divided by a standard error.

Comment: It is correct to say tat to determine  if residual belong to normal distribution, I can set up such hypothesis schema:

H0: { the residual belong to normal distribution }
H1: { the residual do not belong to normal distribution }

Test: $Z_{stat} = \frac{E(e) – \mu_0}{\sigma / \sqrt{N}}$

I can proceed normalizing my residual and compare to a standard normal distribution: Standardize residual:

$Z_E = \frac{\sum{(e-E(e))}}{VAR_{between}}$

Setup test:  $\mu_0 = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$

Test: $Z_{stat} = \frac{Z_E}{1 / \sqrt{N}}$

if $ |Z_{stat}| > z_{(1-\alpha/2)} $ reject H0
is ok?